# Common_Model.php exists, but doesn't declare class Common_Model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I tried checking all the names. It is working fine in **php 5.3** but not working in **php 5.5**

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: RuntimeException
>
> Message: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\application\models/Common_Model.php
>   exists, but doesn't declare class Common_Model
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\system\core\Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 306
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\application\controllers\Auth.php Line: 7
>   Function: __construct
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\index.php Line: 292 Function:
>   require_once

In the message, I can see an unexpected backslash in front of `Common_Model.php`. `Message: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\application\models/Common_Model.php exists, but doesn't declare class Common_Model`

`Common_Model.php` contains:

```
<? if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Common_Model extends CI_Model {


        public function __construct()
        {
                // Call the CI_Model constructor
                parent::__construct();
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

---

**EDIT**

I just changed Common_Model.php to Common_model.php and still getting the same error

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: RuntimeException
>
> Message: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\application\models/Common_model.php
>   exists, but doesn't declare class Common_model
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\system\core\Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 306
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\application\controllers\Auth.php Line:
>   7 Function: __construct
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\index.php Line: 292 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: codeigniter version ?

Comment: According to the docs the name of model class must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your web server doesn't like php shorthand operator. Just change `<?` to `<?php` and it should be all good.

Comment: i have the same problem. But its not working even in <?php ?> this tag.

Comment: I had the same problem but later on found that i have model with name of like Raw_material.php ... instead it should be Raw_material_model.php..

Comment: I have same error above. Just update PHP version 5.6 to 7.4 (7.1, 7.2, 7.3) is working well

Answer (score 5):

Try this

file name should be `Common_model.php`

and inside that

```
<?php

    if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
        exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Common_model extends CI_Model {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function getUser()
        {
            # Your query goes here
        }

    }
```

**In Controller**

```
$this->load->model('Common_model'); # Load Model
$result = $this->Common_model->getUser(); # Access the model function
```

Comment: it was not working with small `m` so i tried capital `M` for the file name. either way, its not helping

Comment: @Prakash set file names small caps and try once

Comment: Please check the update, I updated the error message.

Comment: @Prakash can you change file name to  **`common_model.php`**

Comment: you claimed more about the `file name`, he claimed more about php operator `<?` and `<?php`

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the name of your model to Common_model.php and the name of the class to Common_model.

Answer (score 2):

Check the class name in Common_model.php it should be like this

```
class Common_model extends CI_Model
```

This error most likely happened as result of using duplicated or misspelled class name in Common_model.php

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of model. For example, if the name of the model is `Common_model.php` and you write in the file `Comn_model extends CI_Model`, we get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think your model file name and controller files name is same. please make it differ and check. It is working fine for me.